# Knowing if a public address is spendable by an HD seed?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bip32-hd-wallets, seed, spending

I want to know if an address is spendable by an HD seed and for that purpose I am using the following command:

```
> bitcoin-cli getaddressinfo 3LFc64RRd96ejjYvm14KaogBF9fmeNmePW | jq '.solvable'
false
```

However as mentioned [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60545/is-it-possible-to-check-if-an-address-was-generated-from-an-hd-public-key) and [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48493/can-you-detect-that-the-addresses-generated-by-an-hd-wallet-came-from-a-single-w) it's impossible to know with 100% certainty that an HD seed can't spend from a certain address as one would need to generate infinite addresses. To counterbalance that I discovered a command that increases the 'search space':

```
> bitcoin-cli keypoolrefill 1000
```

However, I am not sure `getaddressinfo` is sentitive to this `keypoolinfo` parameter or is just checking the addresses so far generated (the ones that can be obtained via `bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 0 true`). I could test this with a second node but my other node might be using another seed to generate new addresses. Even though I used `sethdseed`, I see a different `xpriv` when dumping the wallet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to enumerate all private keys using Bitcoin Core's wallet is extremely inefficient. Furthermore, any address that you generate in Bitcoin Core will inherently come from a HD seed because Bitcoin Core is a HD wallet and uses a HD seed. You also aren't going to get any information for a HD address that is not part of your wallet.

> However, I am not sure `getaddressinfo` is sentitive to this `keypoolinfo` parameter or is just checking the addresses so far generated (the ones that can be obtained via `bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 0 true`).

It is "sensitive" to the keypool. When you add keys to the keypool, they are actually generated and saved to the wallet file along with some metadata. `getaddressinfo` looks up whatever metadata is available regardless of the associated key being in the keypool or not.

> I could test this with a second node but my other node might be using another seed to generate new addresses.

Unless you have explicitly set a specific seed, then it most definitely is. Otherwise that would be a security vulnerability and anyone could steal anyone else's coins if they all used the same seed.

> Even though I used sethdseed, I see a different xpriv when dumping the wallet.

You need to provide the seed of your first wallet. Otherwise it will generate a new random seed and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, good to know `getaddressinfo` is 'sensitive to `keypoolrefill`. Is there any way to read the information contained inside `wallet.dat` (or `fee_estimates.dat` for that matter?)


Regarding the last the last topic, yes, I know every new wallet will have a random new seed by default, it just seemed that I was not 'overriding' this new seed with the `sethdseed` command that I used to import